# What happens when you compare 2 pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, compare, series

I ran up against unexpected behavior in pandas when comparing two series.  I wanted to know if this is intended or a bug.

suppose I:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], name='Value')
y = pd.Series([0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2], index=['c', 'f', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'd'], name='Value')

x > y
```

yields:

```
a     True
b    False
c     True
d    False
e    False
f    False
Name: Value, dtype: bool
```

which isn't what I wanted.  Clearly, I expected the indexes to line up.  But I have to explicitly line them up to get the desired results.

```
x > y.reindex_like(x)
```

yields:

```
a     True
b     True
c     True
d    False
e    False
f    False
Name: Value, dtype: bool
```

Which is what I expected.

What's worse is if I:

```
x + y
```

I get:

```
a    1
b    1
c    1
d    2
e    2
f    2
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

So when operating, the indexes line up.  When comparing, they do not.  Is my observation accurate?  Is this intended for some purpose?

Thanks,

-PiR

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't feel right at all.

Comment: There is an issue about this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1134, and a closed PR (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6860)

Comment: Looks like it has to be expressed as `(x-y)>0` instead of `x>y` to have the elements aligned up then...

Comment: nice comments on: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1134.  Read especially snth comment:  " At some point I did check the documentation to see if my understanding of index alignment was correct and there was no mention there that this only applies to the +, -, *, / operators and not to ==, !=, <, <=, >, >=."

Comment: can't seem to use series != series, does not produce correct values. pandas version '0.23.4'

Answer (score 10):

Bug or not. I would suggest to make a dataframe and compare the series inside the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], name='Value_x')
y = pd.Series([0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2], index=['c', 'f', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'd'], name='Value_y')

df = pd.DataFrame({"Value_x":x, "Value_y":y})
df['Value_x'] > df['Value_y']

Out[3]:

a     True
b     True
c     True
d    False
e    False
f    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Small point, you could alternatively build the data frame from the series with  `df=pd.concat([x,y], axis=1)`.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for pointing that out. I do not feel this is as explicit as my code though. "Explicit is better than implicit" - Zen of python

Comment: As you please, but `pd.concat` is very much the standard idiom in Pandas.