# Pandas: `a < b` behaves differently than `a.lt(b)`

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following series

```
x = pd.Series([1, 2], index=['a', 'b'])
y = pd.Series([1, 2], index=['b', 'a'])
```

When I try

```
x < y
```

I get an error

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

However, with

```
x.lt(y)
```

it produces the corrent result.

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) states that they should be equivalent (with the exception of missing values)

Is this a bug in pandas, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25435229/2336654

Comment: @piRSquared: must be a previous version, in my case `x > y` crashes

Comment: yikes!  what version?

Comment: @piRSquared: `0.24.2`. at least, failing is better than what happens in your case...

Comment: Oh, you mean it raises the ValueError?  Yeah, that was the improvement they made.  I asked that question almost 5 years ago.  If you really didn't want to use `pd.Series.lt` you could align the series first `x, y = x.align(y); x < y`